# JQuery datatable.net (datatable.js) - Dynamically Change Settings

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using JQuery DataTable and I want to dynamically change the settings (ideally ***WITHOUT*** having to delete/recreate the table).  Is there a way to rebind the table or is that not possible?

I have provided a live demo [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Me7Zm/19/).

In my current example, I only want to change the sPaginationType setting. My goal is to do the following:

---

**BEFORE**

[image: Before the clicking 'Change Type']

**AFTER**

[image: Before the clicking 'Change Type']

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wanted to change iDisplayLength and found the answer [here](http://my-learningflex.blogspot.com/2012/04/dynamically-change-idisplaylength-of.html). I wrote

```
oTable.fnSettings()._iDisplayLength = 100;
oTable.fnDraw(false);
```

Maybe you'll have to look through all settings to find your property.